# Can't install Racer : "pub(restricted) syntax is experimental (see issue #32409)"

Tags: rust, package, syntax-error, atom-editor, rust-cargo

It seems that the source code for Racer itself has some errors preventing it from installing. I've tried to install via both `cargo install racer` and by trying to compile it myself from Racer's source code.

[image]

How am I suppose to successfully install it? I need at least the `bin` file to use the Racer Atom package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `pub(restricted)` syntax has been stabilized in [Rust 1.18](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1180-2017-06-08), so you must be using an older version of Rust. Updating to Rust 1.18 or later should fix the problem.

Remember that new Rust versions are released every six weeks, so remember to check regularly if you're up to date.

Comment: Weird... I downloaded the newest version yesterday and installed it to replace the older version I had... But now I see that I'm still on version 1.14 for some reasons... How to correctly reinstall it?

Comment: I used the given rustup-init.exe program to install it, but no options to uninstall here...

Comment: You probably installed 1.14 with the Windows installer, not with rustup. The Windows installer installs Rust system-wide, while rustup installs Rust for the current user only, and on Windows, the system PATH takes precedence over the user's PATH at logon. Check in Programs and Features if Rust is there and uninstall it from there. You may also have to log out and log in again to refresh the PATH environment variable (if you didn't already do so since running rustup).

Comment: Ok thanks! Finally I used the `rustup update` command and it seemed to work, thanks!

Comment: @lolgab123 It's a good practice on StackOverflow to also vote up the answer you accepted. Not doing that always makes the one providing the answer go: "what did I do wrooong for not deserving the upvote :'(?!" ;-)

Comment: Noted! Not enough rep for the vote to display, but it says it was registered so should be fine :)